# vue export default fail in typescript via parcel

Tags: typescript, vue.js, parcel

I use vue + TypeScript via Parcel to run a demo, and throw the error in browser after bootstap succeed:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:7878 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
    at Object.exports.install (vue.runtime.esm.js:7878)
    at Home.vue:17
    at Object.parcelRequire.11.vue-hot-reload-api (Home.vue:17)
    at newRequire (main.54d39494.js:48)
    at localRequire (main.54d39494.js:54)
    at Object.parcelRequire.2.vue (Home.vue:17)
    at newRequire (main.54d39494.js:48)
    at parcelRequire.11 (main.54d39494.js:80)
    at main.54d39494.js:106
```

The error occur in **index.js**

```
exports.install = function (vue, browserify) {
  if (installed) { return }
  installed = true

  Vue = vue.__esModule ? vue.default : vue
  version = Vue.version.split('.').map(Number) // Vue.version is undefined
```

Here is my demo files:

**Home.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <img src="../assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import HelloWorld from '../components/HelloWorld.vue'

@Component({
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
})
export default class Home extends Vue {}
</script>
```

What's the wrong with `export default` ?

The typescript configuration is there anything wrong?

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "esnext.array", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "tests/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean the `dist` and `.cache` directory in root every time start.

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "rm -rf .cache && rm -rf dist",
    "prestart": "yarn clean",
    "start": "parcel public/index.html",
    "build": "parcel build public/index.html"
  },
```